# CAML query with Beginwith/EQ/Contains/ Retrieving All rows from Lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml

I have a caml query to retrieve only specific row which matched to the criteria,
but it returns all the items in the LIST,

```
@"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
```

with c# code it is like below

```
string getAllquery = @"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
            ServerProperties.custom.ServerProperties SP = new ServerProperties.custom.ServerProperties();
            SPWeb _SPWeb = SP.GetConnected();
            SPList _SPlist = _SPWeb.Lists["Orders"];
            SPListItemCollection PubCollection = _SPlist.GetItems(getAllquery);
```

This query working perfect with CAML builder.

what i have missed here.?

Comment: Do you know that you need to use item ID when using Lookup in a CAML query?

Comment: then how is it working in CAML builder?

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where>"
```

Try add `<View><Query>...</Query></View>`
in your code

```
"<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>"
```

Look this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems.aspx

Something like this

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>";
        ListItemCollection collListItem = targetList.GetItems(query);
```

**EDIT**

For `query.ViewXml` write

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>...</Where></Query></View>";
```

And for `query.Query` write without `<View>` and `<Query>`

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.Query = "<Where>...</Where>";
```

Comment: tthank you for your answers,does it work when it comes to c# with "query" tag?

Comment: .Query already have <Query> tag

Answer (score 1):

Adding Orderby element was helped to make it work as follows.

```
 @"<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='custaname' /><Value Type='Lookup'>Prab</Value></BeginsWith></Where><orderby><FieldRef Name='title' Ascending='false;/></orderby>";
```